# Another word/way to describe "Core Self"

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, expressions, terminology

I'm looking for another word/description that describes the part of yourself that feels like the core to your soul. The part of yourself that speaks your sincere truth. Other examples (or similar to) that already exist are:

-Self concept 
-Self Principal

I need to use this description to describe the difference between when you are speaking from a place of external influence (expectations, social pressures) and the place that you sincerely connect with (core truth/self).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much

Comment: The classic term in my field is simply *the Self*, typically in contrast to various *roles*.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions everyone. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could say **true self**, the definition according to MW[1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/one%27s%20true/real%20self):

> the type of person one really is

Example sentences (from OLD[2](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/self), under *more example sentences* for point 1):

> ‘He understood me and I didn't have to hide my true self from him.’[2](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/self)
>
> ‘Where you expect to find your true inner self, you will come face-to-face with a mob of strangers.’[2](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/self)
>
> ‘Now I gently introduce others to their intuition and often their true selves.’[2](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/self)

Another, perhaps even more suited word is **inner self**, definition according to CD:

> a person's true or internal mind, soul, or nature[3](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/inner-self)

Example sentence:

> 'a quest to find your inner self and your own uniqueness'[3](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/inner-self)

Answer (score 0):

The word “essence” may do the trick:

> (Latin, esse, to be) The basic or primary element in the being of a thing; the thing's nature, or that without which it could not be what it is. A thing cannot lose its essence ... (From Oxford Reference, online)